# How to find classes, namespace and project folders in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am handling a big WPF application that contains more than 100 projects and and 100s of classes. To modify some areas, I need to find the xmal files and the right projects, classes and namespace. Unfortunatelly, naming is not always helpful. Is there any helpful options in Visual studio.

Comment: Go to definition? (In Rider it works across projects or built-in but in VS I don't remember)

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori I want to find the file in Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search input in the solution explorer tab on the right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use view class diagram for this. You can check how to install and run the component from the link below. I hope it solves your problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2019